# MySQL Selecting from One table into Another Based on ID

Tags: mysql, database, select, select-into

I'm having a problem with MySQL

I have two tables, I want to store Val1 from Table 2 into Val2 in Table 1

Table1

```
ID-----Val1-----Val2
1------A--------NULL
2------B--------NULL
3------C--------NULL
4------D--------NULL
5------E--------NULL
```

Table2

```
ID-----Val1
1------aaa
2------bbb
3------ccc
4------ddd
5------eee
```

So that Table1 now looks like

Table1

```
ID-----Val1-----Val2
1------A--------aaa
2------B--------bbb
3------C--------ccc
4------D--------ddd
5------E--------eee
```

Right now, I have

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Val2) SELECT Val1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.ID=Table2.ID;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either a subquery ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/spal4Sr98A)):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Val2 = ( SELECT Val1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID )
WHERE Val2 IS NULL
```

or a multi-table update ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/C4j58w4U58)):

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table1.Val2 = Table2.Val1
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table1.Val2 IS NULL
```

or the same with an explicit `JOIN` ([SQLize](http://www.sqlize.com/3648SY0xzL)):

```
UPDATE Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
SET Table1.Val2 = Table2.Val1
WHERE Table1.Val2 IS NULL
```

(I assume you only want to update the rows in `Table1` for which `Val2` is NULL.  If you'd rather overwrite the values for all rows with matching `ID`s in `Table2`, just remove the `WHERE Table1.Val2 IS NULL` condition.)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
set table1.val2 = table2.val1
```